# Web api variables with numbers is not working

Tags: javascript

I try to use this API: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/ .
Everything worked well until I tried to get the `24h_volume_usd` variable. Javascript is having trouble with the "24" at the beginning of the variable.

This is my first problem and the second one is that I can't display the `market_cap_usd` / `available_supply` / `total_supply` / `max_supply` / `price_btc`. I tried to find the reason but I have no idea. 4 of this 5 variables are really "high" numbers. Something with this?

Here is my code: http://gg.gg/8psga (jsfiddle link).

Comment: You need to wrap it in square brackets "[]" instead. data[0]['24h_volume_usd']

Comment: Thx mate it works now, but i have still the problem that  "max_supply" and "last_updated" dont get displayed. any idea here?

Comment: please copy/paste the relevant part of your code, most people will not click on an external link for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

try this,updated a little problem

https://jsfiddle.net/xianshenglu/rj8cqLa8/5/

```
<p class="cmc-max_supply"></p><!--new added-->
$('.cmc-last_updated').append(data[0].last_updated);/*change last_updated to cmc-last_updated*/
```

Comment: thx you very much, i didnt see this 2 little faults! sorry for posting things like this here. Im sorry :(

Comment: try to be more careful